# What does 1000 mean in chgrp and chown?

Tags: centos, kubernetes

I am reading a blog to integrate EFK(a log system) into k8s in centos 7.4. There are following instructions:

```
# mkdir ~/es_data
# chmod g+rwx es_data
# chgrp 1000 es_data
# chown 1000 -R es_data

# ls -l /root/es_data/
total 8
drwxrwxr-x 2 1000 1000 4096 Jun  8 09:50 ./
drwx------ 8 root root 4096 Jun  8 09:50 ../
```

I log in as root. The instructions say, If I do chgrp 1000 es_data and chown 1000 -R es_data, the director's owner and group would be 1000. But when I follow the instructions:

I see following:

```
 drwxr-xr-x.  2 master16g master16g    6 Jul 11 15:27 es_data
```

The owner and group appears to machine hostname, `master16g`.

Could someone drop me hints what happens here for `chgrp 1000 and chown 1000`?

Comment: I read man chgrp, but I do not understand why 1000 would change to hostname.

Comment: `grep 1000 /etc/group` , `grep 1000 /etc/passwd`

Comment: This was the answer. It didn't click yet?

Comment: First of all, nobody other then you knows what that instruction is... however, i think this is about ES docker image. If you run official ES docker image - you'll see, that `elasticsearch` UID is `1000` and `elasticsearch` GID is also `1000`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`chown` changes the owner, `chgrp` changes the group. Because you have user and group both named `master16g` having `1000` as UID and GID respectively, this is why you see the user name and the group name on the list. `chown` accepts UID as parameter as well as username, this is well documented in the manual. `chgrp` also accepts GID and group name. You can change both also with one command `chown 1000:1000 es_data -R` or `chown master16g:master16g es_data -R`.

First Linux user has usually UID/GID 1000.

For instance, if you `chown 0:1000 file` you will see `root:master16g` as the file owner.

You can get the details of the `elasticsearch` user by running `id elasticsearch`.

Comment: But what's the purpose why instruction ask us to change owner and group both to 1000, or first linux user? But the screen show numerical 1000.

Comment: Those are Linux basics. Without changing the permissions your user won't be available to do any changes on the given directory or underlying files. [Not sure why did you put those file on `/root` though](https://www.howtogeek.com/124950/htg-explains-why-you-shouldnt-log-into-your-linux-system-as-root/).

Comment: EFK is supposed to run as user elasticsearch, and normally user elasticsearch has uid/gid of 1000/1000, that's why the instruction. But in your container another user, master16g , occupied this id, that confused you.